# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual booting problems

Tags: windows-7, bios, bootloader, easybcd, ubuntu-14.04

I think I have destroyed my PC system and now it won't even boot.

I was trying to configure dual boot with Ubuntu installed after Windows 7. However it always booted into Windows, bypassing the dual boot option page. Then I installed EasyBCD and edited the entries in my boot menu. There are other entries other than Windows 7, as I have installed CentOS and Ubuntu 12 and those entries were still there.

Besides these, DVD, hard disk, USB entries also displayed under the edit entries page. I was assuming they are useless since the path of these entries are null. So I deleted everything, left only the Windows 7 and added Ubuntu in the add entries page.

Then disaster came. After I restarted, I cannot boot into any system. The PC didn't even read the hard disk or the DVD drive. Pressing F2 also didn't work, as the system is waiting forever to open the BIOS setup page.

Does anyone know where I am wrong and how should I go with the fix? If there is nothing I can do, will changing the hard disk or flashing the CMOS help?

Comment: Sorry the tag is typo, should be Ubuntu14.04. I am using my mobile phone...

Comment: I've edited your post, in order to make it clearer and also to change the tags. If you have your Windows 7 installation DVD (and if you can access it), you can try to recover the bootloader, using the steps depicted [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/#Attempt_One_Automated_Repair) (although I have always had success with the nuclear holocaust attempt). Flashing the BIOS shouldn't be needed, as you didn't mess with it in the first place.